# FIRInstanceID getting nil in FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Sandbox

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Hello I am using first time FCM push notification I have implemented FCM with this code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            FIRApp.configure()
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
                                                         name: kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification, object: nil)
        }   
func tokenRefreshNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
        print("refresh token call")
           let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()!
            print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")

            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(refreshedToken, forKey: "deviceToken");
            // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.

            connectToFcm()
            updateDeviceToken()
    }
func connectToFcm() {
        FIRMessaging.messaging().connectWithCompletion { (error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Connected to FCM.")
            }
        }
    }
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
       FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Sandbox)
       /*when I comment above line app works fine but not receiving notificaiton 
        in background and If i uncomment above line than app crashes 
        for the first time when I launch on device */
} 
  func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    connectToFcm()
}
```

Console log is printing `<FIRInstanceID/WARNING> APNS Environment in profile: development` before app crash.

Now issue is when I set `FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Sandbox`  then app crashes when i launch first time bcaz of i am getting `FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()!` nil in `tokenRefreshNotification` method.
And if I not set any APNS Token to `FIRInstanceID` then app works fine but i am not receiving background notification in this scenario. and also give me solution how to check `FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()!` is nil or not

Comment: Sometimes you will get nil for the token in tokenRefreshNoification, this may occur if the the initially generated token is quickly replaced by a new one. You should get another callback to tokenRefreshNotification with another non nil token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my problem with crash handling into `tokenRefreshNotification` Method. I am checking TokenId is nil or not with this code and now my app is not crashing and also I am getting token id:

```
func tokenRefreshNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
      //  print("refresh token call")
        guard let contents = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()
        else {
            return
        }
           // let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()!
            print("InstanceID token: \(contents)")

            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(contents, forKey: "deviceToken");
            // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.

            connectToFcm()
            updateDeviceToken()
    }
```